# How to change the first column to text format in SQL to XLS?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, excel, mysqli

```
    <?php

    require '../config.php';
    error_reporting(0);

    if (!is_admin()) redirect('../login.php');


    $qry = "SELECT * FROM siswa";
    $s = mysqli_query($db,$qry);

// rename file xls
$filename = "export_data_" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

// Fungsi header dengan mengirimkan raw data excel
header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");

// Mendefinisikan nama file ekspor "hasil-export.xls"
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$filename'");
echo "<table border='1'>";

$i = 0;
while($row = $s->fetch_assoc())
{
    if ($i == 0) {
      $i++;
      echo "<tr>";
      foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $value) {
      echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

I have script, but if there are text value in the first column "0000045", it will be just "45" not "0000045". I want this value still "0000045" not "45". How to change the first column to text format in SQL to XLS?

Comment: Note that you're not creating an xls file, simply a file with an extension of `.xls`, containing html markup... modern versions of MS Excel will tell you that the format and extension don't match when you try to open the file

Comment: you're right. I'm not creating an xls file. Now, I've resolve my problem using phpexcel. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because first column in from your result might be a `number` and when it gets stored in xls, preceding zeroes gets trimmmed. You might want to convert the number to `string` before writing to prevent this, e.g.:

`(string) $key` or `(string) $value`

this will give you string value.

Answer (score 0):

The MS Excel importer for an html file will treat numerics as numbers, and apply default number styles to them. If you want a numeric value to be treated as a string, then either create a native format BIFF (xls) or OfficepenXML (xlsx) file which will allow you to set styles, or set the value as a string, or treat it as a formula, e.g:

```
="000045"
```

This will display it as `000045` in the cell, although it will appear as the formula in the editing bar